# Changing linked list into template

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I've written a linked list which stores informations about students. How can I change it to a template, which could have store ints or any other type? Do I have to overload methods in linked list class, cause now they take 6 arguments? I mean, now the method for inserting at end(for student data) looks like this:

```
void insertAtEnd(int index, string name, string surname, int yearOfStudy, string fieldOfStudy, string specialty);
```

And if I want to store ints, it will look like this:

```
void insertAtEnd(int Data);
```

So if I want to use templates for adding students and for example integers, should it look like this?

```
template <class T>
  Class llist{
  void insertAtEnd(int index, string name, string surname, int yearOfStudy, string fieldOfStudy, string specialty);
  void insertAtEnd <T Data>;
}
```

Here is implementation of student and linkedlist class:

```
class student {
public:
    int index;
    string name;
    string surname;
    int yearOfStudy;
    string fieldOfStudy;
    string specialty;
    student *next; //pointer to next item
    student();
};

student::student() {
next = 0;
}

class llist {
  public:
    void insertAtEnd (int index, string name, string surname, int yearOfStudy, string fieldOfStudy, string specialty);
    void insertAtBeginning (int index, string name, string surname, int yearOfStudy, string fieldOfStudy, string specialty);
    void insertAtGivenPosition(int a, string n, int index, string name, string surname, int yearOfStudy, string fieldOfStudy, string specialty);
    void findStudent(int index, string surname);
    void deleteLast ();
    void deleteSelected(int index, string surname);
    void deleteAll ();
    void displayList ();
    student *first; //pointer on first elem
    llist();
};
```

Comment: Consider using `std::list` or even `std::forward_list` instead of intrusive members. As for your question, I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you simply want to allow users to insert using *just* an index value, you can simply use [function overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). In short, you may have many functions with the same name provided their parameters are sufficiently distinct. The compiler will use the correct one for the arguments provided to the function call.

Comment: I had to implement list by myself, couldn't use std::forward_list. At first, I had to implement list that stores students. So I did it and it's working good. Now I have to redo it with templates, so the list could store any type of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the constraints of your question, if it where me, I would change your class structure to:

```
class student {
public:
    int index;
    string name;
    string surname;
    int yearOfStudy;
    string fieldOfStudy;
    string specialty;
    //student *next; //pointer to next item
    student();
};

template <class T>
class node {
  T data;
  node<T> *next;
}

template <class T>
class llist {
public:
  void insertAtEnd (const T &data);
  .
  .
  .
private:
  node<T> *list;
}
```

Take a look at the above psuedo code and see how/if it answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

make a constructor for the types you want to store and then you only have to send one parameter. Or you could pass in an initializer list for simple objects :-

```
push( {"student name", "age", major} );
```

Technically, that's only one parameter, assuming that the fields match the order in the "student" struct/class, so they're only passed as one thing. You can then easily recode the list as a template . Or you call the constructor in the push command:

```
push( Student("student name", "age", major) );
```

If you treat the data as a single object then it's easier to convert your list to a generic template because it's no longer closely coupled with the data. The format of the data are details that the data object is supposed to handle.

Comment: If you want to go this route, you can use variadic templates and support any constructors your type offers, rather than limiting yourself to exactly 1 argument.

Comment: IDK if the questioner is ready for variadic templates if he wants to just get a basic list working at this stage.

Comment: Multiple ways to do this: I would: *not* refactor this directly to a template; Instead, you: (1) Build a new template-based linked list class `llist` that has *nothing* to do with `student` (if it does; it's wrong). (2) Remove the `next` pointer from `student`; it is no longer needed. Change your existing class to be `student_list`, a class that encapsulates a single member `llist<student>`. The member functions can remain the same (or similar), but rather than manage the list directly, they instead mostly forward calls to the `llist<student>` member. That's pretty-much it.

Comment: Oh yeah I just noticed the next pointer in the student class. That is a bit too closely coupled with the data.

Comment: That's why I like this site, always somebody will give a good hint or advice, not like as in the forums in my native language. Big thanks to you guys, now it's way clearer for me.